# Given four points $A, B, C, D$ in a straight line, find a point $O$ in the same straight line such that $OA: OB = OC:OD$

Tags: geometry

I've been on this problem for an entire day. The only thing I learnt is that $O$ is between $A$ and $B$, I feel like I am missing something simple.

Comment: First, given a point P in (AB), how would you construct Q in (AB) such that PA:PB=QC:QD ?

Comment: One way of making progress (not necessarily the best or the easiest) is to introduce co-ordinates on the line, with $x$ the co-ordinate of $O$ you have $\frac {a-x}{b-x}=\frac {c-x}{d-x}$ which reduces to a linear equation [ignoring the infinite solution] and identifies the point you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Make a parallel copy of the line, containing points $A', B',C', D'$. Let $Q$ be the intersection of $A'C$ and $B'D$. Then for any line $\ell $through $Q$, let $O'$ and $O$ be the intersection points with the two parallel lines. Then $O'A':O'B'=OC:OD$. Now what you want is that $O'$ is the parallel copy of $O$, i.e., take $\ell$ perpendicular to the given line (i.e., parallel to $AA'$).

Comment: Thanks! Nice trick. Can't believe I missed that.